# Remove card on button click JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am making a Kanban board, I have a column where inside of it, it's divided using a grid pane between the header and a list of cards below. I am building this using a scene builder.

So the hierarchy is

```
Anchor Pane(column) -> Gridpane(Seperate header and cards) -> Vbox(where I place my list of cards) -> AnchorPane(cards) -> Button(each card has a button)
```

When I press the button on the card, I want it to remove the card that I clicked on.

I have done the following

```
@FXML
public void delete() {
    Parent parent = button.getParent();
    col1.getChildren().remove(parent);  //col1 is the column
}
```

However nothing happens when I press the button, the card does not get deleted and I do not know why. If someone can help me out that would be great.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: @kleopatra I used scene builder to make the GUI(it's in a fxml file), how can I make a minimal reproducible code with that?

Comment: don't understand what you are asking - how can you not? I can't imaging _any_ context/toolchain that hinders you to provide a [mcve] .. you read the referenced help page, didn't you ;)

Comment: Scene Builder is a [WYSIWYG editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) for FXML files. In other words, it saves the content to an FXML file which you can then inspect or modify at will. In order to provide a [mre] you would have to provide a minimal FXML file, a minimal controller class, and the minimal code necessary to launch the application. Keep in mind that minimal code must still be _complete_ (as described in the help page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the code as follows:

```
@FXML
public void delete() {
    Parent card = button.getParent();
    ((VBox) card.getParent()).getChildren().remove(card);
}
```

Comment: Thank you,  that worked. May I ask what was the reason for my code not working?

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing your code. I'm not sure what `col1` refers to.  If it is the `VBox` then it should be the same thing as what I wrote. But as you had a problem, it must be something else.

Comment: col1 refers to the Column, Vbox is inside the column where the cards are placed. Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: Right, so the card isn't a child of the Column, but a child of the VBox. So you trying to remove it from the Column does nothing. It just gets ignored.

Comment: This will work for a single card only unless the card has it's own fxml... (Only a single value can be stored in the `button` field...)

Comment: @fabian you're correct this would only work for a single card, would getting the fx:id of the button that I click on work?

Comment: @rex I'd suggest adding an event parameter to the method and retrieving the `Button` via `Event.source`. The `fx:id` is basically only a string and the only thing you could do with this in this case (unless you've got access to the `FXMLLoader.namespace`) would be to use reflection to access the field, which should be avoided in general.